# R: Pie Chart shading lines over some colored slices

Tags: r, pie-chart

As the title states I would like to produce a pie chart with some of the slices having both: colour and coloured shading lines (hachures) on top. I manage to give the right slices the shading lines:

```
# At first create data
ges <- 94969
alle <- c(6379/ges,22264/ges,11018/ges,2079/ges,444/ges,7268/ges,2204/ges,322/ges,100/ges,9236/ges,1872/ges,5934/ges,4428/ges,14689/ges,3631/ges,1243/ges,1858/ges)
pct <- round(alle/sum(alle)*100, digits=2)
pct1 <- pct; pct1[pct1 < 0.3] <- NA
pct2 <- pct; pct2[pct2 >= 0.3] <- NA
pctgr <- c(round((6379+22264+11018+2079+444+7268+2204+322+100)/ges*100, 2), round((9236+1872+5934+4428+14689)/ges*100, 2), round((3631+1243+1858)/ges*100, 2))
lbls <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA, paste0("Gras- und\n Staudenfluren\n", pctgr[1], " %"),NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
          paste0("Wälder und Forste\n", pctgr[2], " %"),NA,NA,NA,
          paste0("Sonstige\n", pctgr[3], " %"))

# Then find out the angles of the slices (in radiant) for labelling:
library(plotrix)
pie(alle, density = c(NA,NA,NA,8,NA,8,8,NA,8,NA,NA,8,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), labels = "",
    col=c("gold","gold3","goldenrod","red","gold4","red","red","darkorange","red","chartreuse4","forestgreen","red","green3","green4","tomato1","tomato2","tomato3"))
winkel <- floating.pie(0, 0, radius = 0.5, alle, plot = FALSE,
                       col=c("gold","gold3","goldenrod","red","gold4","red","red","darkorange","red","chartreuse4","forestgreen","red","green3","green4","tomato1","tomato2","tomato3"))

# Finally plot the pie and label it:
windows(width = 10, height = 8)
pie(alle, density = c(NA,NA,NA,8,NA,8,8,NA,8,NA,NA,8,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), labels = "",
    col=c("gold","gold3","goldenrod","red","gold4","red","red","darkorange","red","chartreuse4","forestgreen","red","green3","green4","tomato1","tomato2","tomato3"))
pie.labels(0, 0, angles = winkel, labels = lbls, radius = 1.04)
pie.labels(0, 0, angles = winkel, labels = pct1, radius = 0.68, cex = 0.75, font =2)
pie.labels(0, 0, angles = winkel, labels = pct2, radius = 0.58, cex = 0.75, font = 2)
```

I had to plot the pie twice, since `plotrix::floating.pie` has no `plot = FALSE` argument, but I need the angles from `plotrix::floating.pie` for labelling with `plotrix::pie.labels` and I know no other possibility for double labelling, but I can't only use `plotrix::floating.pie`, since it doesn't accept a vector for shading (only one number for the shading density that is applied to all of the pie).
As you can see the shaded slices have no filling colour. How could I change that?